# Configure file in Qt

Tags: linux, qt

I have downloaded 'qtxmlpatterns-opensource-src-5.4.1' for installing on Ubunta Linux. but I can not find configure file for writing ./configure.
which is a necessary step for installation process.
whether this file is available in this version or I should find it in another way?

Comment: qtxmlpatterns... is one of the Qt's modules. You need to download the whole source tree.

Comment: can you suggest me whole source tree?

Comment: You can use the following documentation to build Qt from sources: http://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Comment: really thanks, whether I should download a full pack of Qt5?because I only want it for reading a XML file

Comment: yes you need all the Qt to be able to read Xml file, there are no parts in Qt

Comment: all the best for you, you helped me much :)